# Read Text From Windows Form

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, hook

I would like, if for no other reason that an academic exercise, to be able to read text written to a form on a Windows Application.  The program appears to be written in non-.NET, but in .NET terms, I think you would describe the program as having a Form with a Label and I would like to read the text from that label.

I believe I can see that text being written to the screen with the User32!TextOut (and in other areas User32!DrawString) function.  However, it would be nice if I didn't have to hook that function to get the information I'm looking for, but instead if I could just read it from the form directly.

**So, given a handle to a Window, is it possible to read the text that has been written to that window with functions like TextOut and DrawString using some similar API or other clever means?**

Or am I going about this the wrong way?  Should I just hook the function and look for the text in every call and pray?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text is stored in the standard way on the control you can use SendMessage

```
Win32.SendMessage(controlHandle, Win32.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, null);
```

If the control was written with security in mind, the text is almost certainly not stored in a format that can be queried through the Windows API.

I used to use a program called [Snadboy Revelation](http://www.snadboy.com/) to grab forgotten passwords out of programs (that were just displaying as *****).  Revelation uses the same technique.  However, most modern software hides the text of password and similar fields so this is not of as much use these days.

UPDATE:

Found [source code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=42017&lngWId=1) for a Windows Spy app.

Comment: This sounds brilliant!  I'll give it a shot! :) And just to be sure: I would be able to do this from another application by using `DuplicateHandle` or similar on the controlHandle, right?

Comment: @omghai2u: You can do this with another process' window handles.  Added a link to source code for a Windows Spy app that will have an implementation.